# Are $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ unbiased estimators of $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$?

Tags: expected-value, regression, linear-regression, parameter-estimation

When we are discussing simple linear regression with:
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + X_i\beta_1 +u_i$$

$\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are estimates of this model using OLS.

With a simple proof we get $E(\hat\beta_0) = \beta_0$ and $E(\hat\beta_1) = \beta_1$, thus proving $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are unbiased of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.

My question is whether this is true the other way around: Are $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$  unbiased estimators of $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of simple linear regression, we are typically interested in estimating the **parameters** $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, which are by assumption fixed real numbers. The Ordinary Least Squares **estimators** can then be obtained by applying the usual formulae to the data points in our sample. What you don't seem to grasp is that an estimator - such as $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ - is indeed a function whose inputs come from our sample (roughly speaking), with a target in mind; whereas a parameter is some (potentially) unknown, fixed quantity which we are interested in approximating by means of some computation (such as an OLS estimate).